# A problem about areas of triangles which belong to ABCD

Tags: geometry

Let ABCD be a convex quadrilateral. How can I prove that the area of ABC is equal to the area of ABD if and only if AB is parallel to CD?

Comment: The triangles have a common base $AB$, hence if they have the same area, they must have the same ... ?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**
$$[ABX]=\frac{|AB|\cdot\text{dist}(AB,X)}{2}$$